# Struggling to build SIP for PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sip

Basically, trying to build SIP so that I can install PyQt4. I manage to use 
    python configure.py
That is completely fine - I get the sipconfig.py file.

Problem comes when I try to build. It won't recognise make. I've tried to get Visual Studio to do it - but that just made me really confused. Any suggestions would be really good - I've tried other solutions and nothing seems to work.

So yeah, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install MinGW , and then set your path to include mnGW and use: `mingw32-make` and `mingw32-make install`

The full detail of this process can be found in [Python web manual](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildPyQt4Windows)